# Why does Firefox put a horizontal scrollbar on my div?

Tags: html, css, linux, firefox

I've got a very simple test case:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="border:2px solid black; overflow: auto;">
      x
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I render it, I get a horizontal scrollbar!

I had been using FF 3.0.3 for Linux, and thought it might be a browser bug, so I upgraded to FF 3.5b4 (the latest release candidate). Still happens.

Is this supposed to happen? Should I file a bug report? Does anyone know of a workaround (edit: one that allows me to continue using overflow:auto)?

Comment: That's odd I don't get a horizontal scroll bar in FF 3.0 or IE7 in windows vista.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There shouldn't be scroll bars for overflow:auto unless the content is actually going beyond the edges of the containing element. This is a bug in Linux versions of Firefox. See the following [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=397367).

Comment: This bug is still present in Firefox 80. (2021)

Answer (score 6):

its your overflow style. change to overflow hidden to remove the scrollbars.

Josh

Comment: Chris Coyier has a fantastic post about the css overflow property a little while ago: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/.

Comment: I know that overflow is helping cause the problem, but I *need* overflow:auto on this. Is a horizontal scrollbar supposed to be an unavoidable side effect?

Comment: what your need for overflow and perhaps i can help suggest an alternative.

Comment: if you need a vertical scroll but not a horizontal one you could use `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

I would file a bug report.  It doesn't render that way on my version (for Windows).

Comment: Yeah, according to the CSS spec, auto should only show scroll bars when necessary.
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow1

Comment: Here's an existing bug report on the topic: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=397367

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your `div` happens to have `width:100%` and therefore overflows when you add border?